# How can we search for column '*' in a database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

If i try to search for column name `'*'` in `php` database, it lists all the column entries. Is there any method to search for column name `'*'` ?

Comment: Can i see your table structure?

Comment: When we do `SELECT * FROM...` it means "select all columns from the table(s)".

Comment: What do you mean column name `"*"`? Do you have a column that has name `"*"`?

Comment: I think the OP has `*` as a column name

Comment: but what if my column name is '*' , i only want to search in that particular column.

Comment: How can you name your column * MySQL will not allow you that

Comment: @AbdulManaf , who said MySQL doesn't allow that?

Comment: @ling.s : I was wrong, I have updated my answer

Comment: It's incredibly stupid to call a column '*', but it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `*` as a column name then surround it with back ticks (`)

```
create table test(`*` int, var2 int);
select `*` from test
```

Here is an example [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62e28/2)

Comment: +1 for giving the correct answer, although I still can't understand why anyone would think a DB setup like this is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TABLE test_(`*` INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> desc test_;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| *     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = '*' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'world';
+-------------+------------+
| COLUMN_NAME | TABLE_NAME |
+-------------+------------+
| *           | test_      |
+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* is a wildcard that is used to denote 'ALL'.
```

So when you are firing an query like select `* from table_name` it gives you all the columns. 
though you can create a column named as * but it is NOT RECOMMENDED at all, as it can create problems with the other queries (when you want to select all of the columns)

Here is another solution if you want * as you column name you can do following:

```
SELECT column_name AS * FROM table_name
```